# GWTP - How to create multiple views depending on formfactor?

Tags: gwt, mobile, tablet, gwtp

How can I create different views for mobile, tablet and desktop using GWTP?
Do I have to have different Ginjectors?
For a mobile presenter i may have more or less presenters, or some functions may be more or less. how can that be handled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a ClientGinjector interface and inherit it in multiple interfaces like a DesktopGinjector,TabletGinjector and so on. You can then create different bindings for your presenters and views. GWTP makes it easier to handle such a scenario. There is an open-source Customer Experience framework which has a sample to create a mobilewebapp using GWTP. You can check it out here- http://code.google.com/p/gwt-cx/